# aurelia-cli css resource failed to load

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm trying to create an `<map>` element with leaflet.
I have added the dependencies in the aurelia.json file from aurelia-cli, the same as I did already for bootstrap before.

```
{
    "name": "leaflet",
    "path": "../node_modules/leaflet/dist",
    "main": "leaflet",
    "resources": [
        "leaflet.css"
    ]
}
```

[github link](https://github.com/dattn/track-interface/blob/66228c23436e682e03c0f7046155527a16b8a965/aurelia_project/aurelia.json)

When I run the app with "au run", the leaflet.css file is correctly integrated in the vendor bundle file.

But when trying to require this file in my map element I get the error:

> "Unhandled rejection Error: Failed loading required CSS file: leaflet/leaflet.css

The map.html file looks like this:

```
<template>
    <require from="leaflet/leaflet.css"></require>
    <div ref="mapNode" style="height: 100%"></div>
</template>
```

[github link](https://github.com/dattn/track-interface/blob/66228c23436e682e03c0f7046155527a16b8a965/src/resources/elements/map.html)

I can't see the difference to the bootstrap package, which works without any problem.

---

After moving the leaflet dependency before that of bootstrap 4, everything seems to work correctly.
[github link](https://github.com/dattn/track-interface/commit/4041912483cd578a37b9a4368913f6e9fd95df04)

Is it possible that bootstrap breaks the requirejs lib or the text plugin?

Answer (score 3):

It's resource plugin fail - sometime after new adding of css-resources to aurelia config file it can't work correct (I'm using bootstrap v4 too).

Solution: go to `aurelia.json` config file and change loader text plugin `stub` to `false` like that:

```
"loader": {
  "type": "require",
  "configTarget": "vendor-bundle.js",
  "includeBundleMetadataInConfig": "auto",
  "plugins": [
    {
      "name": "text",
      "extensions": [
        ".html",
        ".css"
      ],
      "stub": false
    }
  ]
},
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked. Do you know what's "stub" doing?

Comment: It's try to load problem data from "node_modules" path on server. You must deploy it additional to server (i.m use firebug to see http-requests and find that modules).